# Flutter[CRUSH] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted problem

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, cross-platform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp7IM.png)

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 6576): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576): Process: com.example.plannertest, PID: 6576
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:435)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.BasicMessageChannel$IncomingMessageHandler$1.reply(BasicMessageChannel.java:222)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.GeneratedAndroidFirebaseAuth$FirebaseAuthUserHostApi$2.success(GeneratedAndroidFirebaseAuth.java:3247)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.GeneratedAndroidFirebaseAuth$FirebaseAuthUserHostApi$2.success(GeneratedAndroidFirebaseAuth.java:3244)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthUser.lambda$getIdToken$1(FlutterFirebaseAuthUser.java:88)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthUser$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onComplete(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:1)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8176)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6576):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
I/Process ( 6576): Sending signal. PID: 6576 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

**Hi all, I started getting this error constantly today and I couldn't find a solution. Can you help me ?**
Pubspec.yamp plugin:

```
   firebase_messaging: ^14.6.2
    firebase_auth: ^4.7.1
    firebase_core: ^2.14.0
    cloud_firestore: ^4.8.1
```

I thought it was related to Firebase. I also wrote a function that allows the user to login on my Splash Screen. I thought it might be doing it while trying to buy tokens, but it explodes as soon as I get the build.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class SplashLogic extends GetxController
    with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;
  late Animation<double> animation;
  bool isOnboard = false;
  EmployeeResponse employeeResponse = EmployeeResponse();
  final AuthRepository _authRepository = AuthRepository();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    animationController = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      vsync: this,
    );
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0.8, end: 1.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController,
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      ),
    );
    animationController.repeat(reverse: true);
    checkLoginStatus();
  }

  Future<void> checkLoginStatus() async {
    try {
      final token = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.getIdToken();
      final userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
      print('userId: $userId');
      kBox.write('userId', userId);
      print('token: $token');
      kBox.write('token', token);
      if (token != null && token.isNotEmpty) {
        employeeResponse = await _authRepository.organizationMe();
        await _authRepository.getEmployeeMe();
        isOnboard = kBox.read('isOnboard') ?? false;
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
        if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
          if (token.isNotEmpty &&
              employeeResponse.success == true &&
              employeeResponse.data != null &&
              employeeResponse.data!.isNotEmpty) {
            Get.off(() => HomeNavBar());
          } else {
            Get.off(() => SignupScreen());
          }
        } else if (isOnboard) {
          Get.off(() => const LoginScreen());
        } else if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null && isOnboard) {
          Get.off(() => const LoginScreen());
        } else {
          Get.off(() => OnboardScreen());
        }
      } else {
        Get.offAll(() => const LoginScreen());
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      Get.offAll(() => const LoginScreen());
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

NOT: It was something related to Firebase's new package. I updated my plugins as follows and the **problem was solved.**

```
firebase_auth: 4.6.3
firebase_auth_platform_interface: 6.15.3
```

Comment: I have the same problem and couldn't find the problem yet, I have the lastest plugings. Only happens when open the app from a terminal state

Comment: started having the same or similar problem with firebase from last 2-3 days.
Please let me know how to fix the problem if you find the solution.

Comment: I have downgraded my Firebase plugin versions as shown. firebase_auth: 4.6.3
firebase_auth_platform_interface: 6.15.3